# What's the vim way to select multiple instances of current word and change them?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

Anyone familiar with Sublime Text's multiple cursor feature will recognize the pattern of doing the following: press a hotkey multiple times to select multiple instances of the word under the cursor and automatically create a new cursor for each of those instances; then edit each instance simultaneously, e.g. by replacing the current word with another word or whatever you want.

The multiple cursors feature is available for vim via [plugin](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors). Before using that plugin, I want (as a new vim user), to check whether there is a more natively vim-like way to achieve the same task.

For instance, I know I could use the `:s` command to do a search and replace (per instructions [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)), but that requires me to (1) type in the word I want to replace (or use the `<C-r><C-a>` shortcut to do so), as opposed to simply using the current word and (2) define a range. Perhaps this is the native vim way to do it, perhaps (likely!) there's another way I don't know.

So what is the native vim way?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I use the `*`, `gn`, and the `.` to make changes.

- Select current word with `*` (go back with `N`)
- Change word with `gn` motion. e.g. `cgnfoo<esc>`
- Repeat via `.` command

Note: If you have many changes then using a substitution command would probably be better.

There is a nice [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode about the `gn` motion: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/).

For more help see:

```
:h *
:h gn
:h .
```

Comment: For future SO users, here's a [very quick and to the point blog post](http://alexkuang.com/blog/2015/01/24/gn-in-vim/) that explains this approach.

Comment: Dug up the ['very quick and to the point blog post'](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329063103/http://alexkuang.com/blog/2015/01/24/gn-in-vim/) ...What is dead may never die ;-)

Comment: The * chooses the next word of the match. Use Ctrl + N to go back to the "original" word and then follow the commands in this answer.

`* => Ctrl + N => cgnfoo<Esc> => . ` (to toggle word by word)

Comment: `<c-n>` goes down linewise by default in normal mode. I think you mean `N` so shift + n key. See `:h CTRL-N` and `:h N`

Comment: Yes, I meant shift + n (not Ctrl + N) but I realized that after 20 minutes and my edit window had passed. Apologies.

Comment: This is really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can record macros in Vim by pressing `q<letter>`.  Macros can include the `n` command to search for the next instance of a word.  You can also go into insert mode while recording (e.g. using the `c` command with a motion such as `iw` to replace the current word).  Press `q` to stop recording, and then press `@<letter>` to replay the macro once.  After that, you can use `@@` to repeat the macro as many times as you like.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I thought about macros but they seem cumbersome for something as quick and dirty as this, but that may be because I haven't gotten into the habit of using macros yet.

Comment: The `.` (dot) command is basically just a macro consisting of your last command.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for other answers, I'm going to post what I'm experimenting with while waiting for vim experts to answer:

```
:.,$s/<C-r><C-a>/foobar/gc
```

to substitute (the `s`) from the current line (the `.`) to the last line (`$`) (with the comma denoting the line range), using the `<C-r><C-a>` combo to copy the current word into the command, then using `gc` to change with confirmation, so I can hit yes/no for each instance then quit when I've done enough.

Comment: Note: `<c-r><c-w>` is the current `word` and `<c-r><c-a>` is the current `WORD`. See `:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W` and `:h word` for more information.

Comment: Thanks @PeterRincker. Time to learn about shortcuts while entering a command (presumably there's a name for that mode?). Love to hear your thoughts on my suggestion compared to your answer in terms of what is most vim-like.

Comment: @PeterRincker - now that I understand `gn` I think that is definitely the default way to go, and the most akin to the Sublime Text pattern. My answer is also a nice trick to have in case you want to selectively confirm the changes, which can be handy.

Comment: You can skip occurrences with `n`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to select and change the words. it might work different for various integrations of vim, but I use it with VS code it changes the words and when I press Enter it will make the changes.

`:%s/old_word/newWord`