# Vim - Select multiple instances of current word and change simultaneously - execute action on all search results without using substitution?

Tags: vim, sublimetext3

I have read the question: [What's the vim way to select multiple instances of current word and change them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130553/whats-the-vim-way-to-select-multiple-instances-of-current-word-and-change-them)

And am not sure if I am doing something wrong but was wondering how to change multiple occurrences of a word (or search result) simultaneously.

Given the block:

```
EXAMPLE_VAR = foo
bar = EXAMPLE_VAR
baz = EXAMPLE_VAR + 1000
```

If I would like to change all occurrences of `EXAMPLE_VAR` to lowercase `example_var`, from what I have read, I would:

1. move cursor to first `EXAMPLE_VAR`
2. <kbd>*</kbd> to select word
3. <kbd>N</kbd> to move back up
4. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> to select the word in visual mode
5. <kbd>u</kbd> to convert to lowercase
6. <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to go to next and repeat as required

Is there a way to make the action repeat automatically on all search results? (I know I could use the substitute or search and replace to do it globally, but that requires typing out all the variable names etc) - This is just one of a few things I find slowing me down coming from Sublime where I would simply:

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select word, repeat a few times to select occurrences
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to change all simultaneously

Comment: You don't need to type out the names when using the substitution, it'll default to the latest search. You can use `*` to set it. You can also get the matched string in the replace part with `&`, and use `\L` to lowercase every character (after the `\L`). All in all you could do: move the cursor to the word, use `*`, then `s//\L&/g`. Though obviously that's rather specific to your example :).

Comment: https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors: True Sublime Text style multiple selections for Vim.

Answer (score 3):

```
guip
```

does exactly what you want with the provided example.

If you really miss Sublime's multiple cursors feature you can look around for a plugin.

Comment: So does `gguG` but i think it is pretty clear what he is looking for. This answer makes the asumption that no other capital letters are in the paragraph which most certainly isn't guaranteed. It is also not an answer to the question in the title. Since I am used to great answers from you i wanna ask, what case do you try to make here? Do I miss something?

Comment: Woah, I've never encountered this before, and it does it so well. Could you please break down exactly how this is interpreted by vim?

edit: Oh I see now, its saying "make {motion} text lowercase" where {motion} is "in paragraph"

Comment: @StunBrick see `:h gu` and `:h ip`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, my point would be that everything is a matter of context in Vim, where you get a toolset rich enough to allow you to build ad-hoc solutions to specific problems. Yes a recursive macro  recording could do it but so would do a substitution or a third party multiple-cursors plugin if one absolutely wants to reduce every problem to a simplified model. Everything looks like a nail when you have a hammer.

Comment: To be clear, I am not a fan of the macro solution ;-) It is just there for completeness. Your statement is correct do, a lot of times there are easier solutions if we look at the context. But as far as SO goes as a site, we can only solve what we got. So i still don't think this answer is any help. But that's okay, it is not about me and I am in no position to judge anyone (and have no interest in it). So I thank you sincerely for your explanation and hope the answer will help a lot of people!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as stated, use a recursive macro:

once you've searched for `EXAMPLE_VAR` it would be like this:

```
qaqqanguw@a
```

But it isn't the best solution. `CTRL-R CTRL-W` could help you, it copies the word under the cursor to the command line. So `/<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>` does the same as `*`.

Then it is easy to use a global command:

```
:g/<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>/norm /<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>guw
```

Or a substitue (thanks Marth):

```
:%s/<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>/\L&/g
```

As Marth already pointed out, if you have already searched for the word, you can replace `/<CTRL-R><CTRL-W>/` in the examples with `//` which just uses the last search (In the second part of the global command you would use `ng` not `//`).